# React-Native Async Storage - Increasing Storage Size not working for Samsung Devices

Tags: react-native, sqlite, asyncstorage

### Current behavior

I set up new storage size to 20MB using this [guide](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size). It works for Xiaomi, Oppo etc devices however not working on Samsung devices.

`Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1`

I was getting this error before adding more spaces and it disappared after adding more spaces on my debug devices except Samsung.
Is there any hardware-based solutions for this?

### Expected behavior

Works on Samsung devices too.

### Repro steps

- Use a data which contains data > 6MB
- Add more spaces using the guide
- Test Samsung and another device

### Environment

- **Platforms tested**:

  - [ x ] Android
  - [ ] iOS
  - [ ] macOS
  - [ ] Windows
- **AsyncStorage version**: 1.13.2
- **Environment**:
  System:
  OS: macOS 11.2.3
  CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700B CPU @ 3.20GHz
  Memory: 77.17 MB / 8.00 GB
  Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
  Node: 15.0.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm: 7.0.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
  CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
  Platforms: iOS 14.2, DriverKit 20.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.2, watchOS 7.1
  Android SDK:
  API Levels: 29, 30
  Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2
  System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
  Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069
  Xcode: 12.2/12B45b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
  Java: 1.8.0_272 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
  @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
  react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
  react-native: 0.64.1 => 0.64.1
  react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
  *react-native*: Not Found

Comment: 20 MB seems to be use to store using Async storage. You have to use some local db and handle the content.

Comment: It's working for iOS & other android devices. This problem appears on Samsung only

Comment: "Working" may be temporary. Because iOS will force crash the app once it reaches max space limitations.Even it might the case with Android app as well when it goes to production. Under stand the concept of storage and memory related issues in real time.